# Capturing the xpath/locator of the Edit Status in Facebook

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to Post a status in FB using selenium. But i am not able to correctly locate the Edit status text and getting NoSuchElementException.
I have tried different xpaths, which are correct too but still i am getting the same exception. 
Please help

Comment: Can you list the Xpaths you tried ?

Comment: Please update your question with the xpath information you're trying to use and your code. There isn't enough information in this question to answer it.

Comment: Sounds like an interview/homework assignment....? I (we?) might be able and/or willing to help if you would provide more information on what you did and researched and what actually failed...

Answer (score 1):

For me, the checklist in a case when Selenium reports that an element is not found is:

- Is the correct page fully loaded in the browser window, driven by Selenium?
- Is the page in the expected state (e.g. user is logged in)?
- Does the XPath expression work on the particular page from a manual browser instance?

---

As a side note: to manually determine if an XPath expression is correct, it can be verified in the browser's console (opened with `Ctrl+Shift+I` or `F12`), utilising Javascript libraries, which may already be provided by the page.

On Facebook, I tested it like this:

```
$x('<my xpath>')
```

In case the XPath is correct, it returns the found element.

To find the button for posting status, The following XPath worked for me:

```
//div[@data-testid='activity-sprout']
```

Which was verified in browser, when I executed in console the following command:

```
$x("//div[@data-testid='activity-sprout']")[0].click()
```